# Replace and Return same result

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code. I need to follow this instruction but I don't understand how to do it. "Replace the code that assigns the cards and score data to the outputArea with a return statement
that returns the same data from the ShowHand function."

```
function showHand(hand, score)
{
   let cards="";
   for(let i=0; i<hand.length; i++)
      cards += hand[i].card + '';
   outputArea.innerText += cards + "" + score + "\n" ;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give more details.

Comment: This is not a place for homework. Show some effort first.
Learn a bit more and come back with a better more clear question.

Comment: How can i show you my effort @Daut? Yes im still learning and i need your guidance guys. I'm asking because i couldn't find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ***outputArea.innerText***

```
function showHand(hand, score){
let cards="";
let result = [];
for(let i=0; i<hand.length; i++)
   cards += hand[i].card + '';
   result.push( cards + "" + score + "\n" ) ;
 };
 return result;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me @squeekyDave but thank you for your help =)